# NativeMessageHandler Giving "Unauthorized" result on PostAsync

Tags: xamarin, mono, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, tls1.2

I am using ModernHTTPClient in my application to access a Secure ReST Service. 
Server is configured with TLS1.2. 
Whenever i try to hit the service with valid user credential, i gets the below error.

> "Unauthorized"
>
> "System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'System.Net.HttpVersion' threw an exception."

Below is the code which i used

```
 NativeMessageHandler handler = new NativeMessageHandler(false, false);
 handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;                    
 handler.EnableUntrustedCertificates();
 handler.Credentials = oNwCred;
 handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic;
 using (var oClient = new HttpClient(handler))
 {
    //Set Timeout
    oClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, C_TIME_OUT, 0);
    oClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

     var oContent = new StringContent(szRequestJson, Encoding.UTF8, C_CONTENT_TYPE);
     return await oClient.PostAsync(szUrl, oContent);
  }
```

Server is configured with self signed certificate.

I have tried the code from Both PCL and from Droid project as well.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards
Vips

Comment: Does it work when not using ModernHttpClient (maybe test in a console app)?

Comment: Where do you populate user credentials?

Comment: Yea it works for successful cases when using HTTPClient, where there is some error thrown from server, it is given as Unauthorized. For now i provided a hard coded network credential, which is filled just before the above code.